# How to make deleting .svn directories work using ant?

Tags: svn, ant

I tried the example in the manual:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
  <fileset dir="${DIR}" includes="**/.svn" defaultexcludes="false"/>
</delete>
```

(where DIR is set to some directory) and it does nothing.  How can this be made to work?  I'm using ant 1.7.0.

FYI: I've tried lots of different combinations of nested elements, `dirset` instead of `fileset` and it still doesn't work.  :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just use **svn export** instead?

Anyway, looks like ( [from here](http://www.jroller.com/stritti/entry/delete_svn_directories_using_an) ) the following should work:

```
<echo level="info">Remove svn-files...</echo>
<delete includeemptydirs="true" >
    <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}" defaultexcludes="false" >
         <include name="**/.svn/" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Comment: I'm not using svn export because I simply need to copy some files from dir1 to dir2 that may include built products; svn export will not copy files that are not under version control.

Comment: Anyway, your example works; however, the nested include is not necessary. The difference that makes it work is the trailing / in "**/.svn/". So, apparently, the ant manual is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following lines:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
   <dirset dir="./" defaultexcludes="false">
      <include name="**/.svn/**" />
   </dirset>
</delete>
```