# how to delete .svn folders using ant script?

Tags: ant

I want to delete .svn folders using ant script. Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

```
<target>
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" >
            <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}" defaultexcludes="false" >
                 <include name="**/.svn/" />
            </fileset>
        </delete>
  </target>
```

in the above script what need to give for target and what is ${checkout.dir}? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make deleting .svn directories work using ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890772/how-to-make-deleting-svn-directories-work-using-ant)

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<project default="run">
  <target name="run">
    <tstamp/>
    <property name="scan.folder" value="." />
    <echo message="Delete all .svn from ${scan.folder}"></echo>
    <delete includeemptydirs="true"  verbose="true">
      <fileset dir="${scan.folder}" includes="**/.svn/**,**/.svn" defaultexcludes="false"/>
    </delete>
  </target>
</project>
```